# Trying to Stop Button From Auto-Submitting With Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a page with a series of inputs, similar to a form but not. Upon pressing Submit, I want to run my function submitForm(). However, every time the page loads, it auto-clicks submit. Any ideas on how to stop this from happening?

JS:

```
function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var fname = document.getElementById(name).value();
    var femail = document.getElementById(email).value();
    var fmessage = document.getElementById(message).value();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "cgi-bin/process.php",
        data: "name=" + fname + "&email=" + femail + "&message=" + fmessage,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
        }
    }
    });
}
function formSuccess(){
    $( "#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
}

$(function() {
    $("#btnContact").on("click", submitForm()); 
});
```

Any my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="name" class="h4">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name"
      required="">
    <label for="email" class="h4">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" 
    required="">
    <label for="message" class="h4 ">Message</label>
    <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message"
    required=""></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id="btnContact" type="submit">Send Message</button>
    <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden">Message Submitted!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing the button type, `type="button"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `()` from your final statement.

`s/submitForm\(\)/submitForm/`.

You are actually calling the function.

http://jsfiddle.net/fx6hefe4/

Will look like this:

`$(function() {
    $("#btnContact").on("click", submitForm); 
});`

Comment: onload line? Sorry not familiar with the syntax

Comment: Your `$(function...);` call is a jquery shorthand for `$(document).ready()`.  https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/31/)**.

Your code work after several changes.

1. Replace :

   ```
   var fname = document.getElementById(name).value();
   var femail = document.getElementById(email).value();
   var fmessage = document.getElementById(message).value();
   ```

   By :

   ```
   var fname = document.getElementById('name').value;
   var femail = document.getElementById('email').value;
   var fmessage = document.getElementById('message').value;
   ```
2. Replace :

   ```
   $("#btnContact").on("click", submitForm());
   ```

   By :

   ```
   $("#btnContact").on("click", function(){
       submitForm();
   });
   ```
3. Replace :

   ```
   <button id="btnContact" type="submit">Send Message</button>
   ```

   By :

   ```
   <button id="btnContact" type="button">Send Message</button>
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! cdbitesky answered first so had to give em the right answer, but I appreciate the answer!